# PageView Builder is not rebuilt

Tags: flutter

I have a screen with a TextField that passes the data to my PageView, but when I pass the data and go back to my screen with PageView, it is not updated. It updates the data only if you run RunDebug again. I want it to rebuild so that the new data can be added.

Is there a way for PageView to be rebuilt?

I do not know what else to do

```
class ContainerSwiper extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ContainerSwiperState createState() => _ContainerSwiperState();
}

class _ContainerSwiperState extends State<ContainerSwiper> {




  ContactHelper helper = ContactHelper();

  List<dynamic> tarefas = List();

  PageController controller;

  int _index = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tarefasHelper();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: <Widget>[ Expanded(child:  SizedBox(
          height: 200, // card height
          child:
    PageView.builder(
            itemCount: tarefas.length,
            controller: controller, 
            onPageChanged: (int index) => setState(() => _index = index),
            itemBuilder: (_, i) {
              return Transform.scale(
                scale: i == _index ? 1 : 0.9,
                child:GestureDetector(
                  onTap: (){
                    _showTarefaPage(tarefa: tarefas[i]);
                  },
                  child: Card(
                  elevation: 6,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      tarefas[i].title,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ));
            },
          ),
        ))]);
  }
void _showTarefaPage({Contact tarefa}) async {
    final recContact = await Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => CreateTarefa(
                  tarefas: tarefa,
                )));
    if (recContact != null) {
      if (tarefa != null) {
        await helper.updateContact(recContact);
      } else {
        await helper.saveContact(recContact);
      }
      _tarefasHelper();
    }
  }
  void _tarefasHelper() {
    helper.getAllContacts().then((list) {
      setState(() {
        tarefas = list;
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: please check this recContact --- it should not be null

Comment: It has come to nothing yet